# ASP.NET Code Analisys on Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: asp.net, code-analysis, fxcop, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install the [Fxcop ASP.NET Security rules](http://fxcopaspnetsecurity.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex as described on a MSDN Magazine article: [Improving ASP.NET Security with Visual Studio 2010 Code Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490350.aspx)

I'm using VS 2010 SP1 Ultimate and I can't make it load the rules to be used in the IDE. I have copy the DLL files the package contains into different folders where VS seems to be looking for the rules but I don't have the ruleset files.

Is anyone aware of a way to make it work without using FXcop externally?

Comment: Yoiu mean ... You have installed FXCop successfully but the rules are not getting loaded?

Comment: I mean in-build VS 2010 Ultimate SP Code Analysis tool.

Comment: What does it show when you Right Click on your project -> choose properties -> in prop window select code analysis tab -> click on OPEN button. Do you see the rules listed there? If not, do you get any specific error's in VS output window?

Comment: I get the default ones that come with VS, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ruleset file with you (one with `*.ruleset` extension) then you add them directly in VS.

> Right Click on your project -> choose properties -> in prop window
>   select code analysis tab -> click on OPEN button

This will open the rules window. Select the `add ruleset` button as depicted in below screen

[image]

This will pop-up another rules window as shown below -> click on `add rules` button -> browse through the file location where the ruleset file is there -> select the file and click OK.

[image]

Comment: The problem here is I don't have the ruleset files, as described in the question, I only have the DLLs files that seems to contain the ruleset files inside. Maybe it's a way to extract them?

Comment: Same issue here any solution to get the .ruleset file for aspnet rules?